# Custom AspNetWindowsAuthProvider

Tags: servicestack

Can I login only specific users with AspNetWindowsAuthProvider in ServiceStack.

I created a CustomAspNetWindowsAuthProvider and I have a table whitelist with allowed users, in the method IsAuthorized I am checking if the user exits in the table, if not exits I returned false but it's not working, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've created a Custom AuthProvider that overrides `AspNetWindowsAuthProvider` and you've override `Authenticate()` it still needs to call `IsAuthorized(user)` in your custom implementation [like it's done in AspNetWindowsAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/04d37ccf026b140d4da64e19d6d3c20f42dcbdd2/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AspNetWindowsAuthProvider.cs#L94).

Comment: Thank u @mythz, I am using the default UserAuth table like whitelist to check if the user exits to authenticate, but when the user doesn't exists it's added automatically, can I prevent it?

Comment: @LestherVega have a look at the base class impl, it throws if !IsAuthorized(user), it can't create a User.